# TypeScript JSDoc annotations for a function that adds an object property

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I'm working in a project with ample JSDoc comments and I want to start taking advantage of `tsc` and [JSDoc style annotations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html).

Given a function that adds a property to an Object like so:

```
/**
 * @param {object} obj
 * @param {string} n
 * @return void
 */
function addName(obj, n) {
    obj.name = n;
}

let thing = {size: "medium"};
addName(thing, "product");
console.log(thing.name);
```

Is there a way to declare that the object will be mutated with an additional property?

Comment: I don't think that that is posible. Because is not posible in typescript. Or It is?

Answer (score 0):

Does this approach fulfil the need of your real case? It superficially resolves the issue you describe, but perhaps you can't change the signatures of anything to adopt this more 'immutable' pattern.

```
function addName<O extends object, V>(obj:O, val:V): O & {name:V} {
    return {
      ...obj,
      name:val
    }
}

let thing = {size: "medium"};
let newThing = addName(thing, "product");
console.log(newThing.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Going down another track, given the current signature of `addName` returns void, you could make it always return boolean and turn it into a type predicate. Then anything guarded by the assignment's boolean return value would be properly typed with the extra known parameter

```
function addName(obj:object, n:string) : obj is typeof obj & {name:string}{
    (obj as any).name = n;
    return true
}

let thing = {size: "medium"};
if(addName(thing, "product")){
  console.log(thing.name);
}
```